# Looking for a simple proof of symmetry of linear susceptibility tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dielectric

**Getting a diagonal susceptibility tensor:**

Define the linear susceptibility tensor as $\chi_{ij}$: $P_i = \epsilon_0\chi_{ij}E_j$, using standard notation for the electric field and the polarization.
If one assumes a toy model with atoms having a harmonic potential:
$$\ddot{x} + 2\gamma\dot{x} + \omega_0^2x = -eE_x(t)/m$$
Now if we put $E_x(t)$ in terms of exponentials/sinusoid with a forcing frequency $\omega$, we can find the steady-state solution in the same manner as a forced harmonic oscillator. Then the $x$ can be used to write $P = -Nex$, with $N$ denoting number density. Finally, we can end up with an expression where $P \propto E$ and obtain the *scalar* susceptibility.

In principle, we can change the value of $\omega_0$ for $y$ and $z$ and write three different equations for the Cartesian axes to generate a diagonal susceptibility tensor, where not all non-zero terms are equal. Obviously, this tensor is symmetric and if we do a similarity transformation, it will stay symmetric.

**Proving symmetry?**

I'm not sure how to extend this basic idea to actually prove that the susceptibility tensor ought to be symmetric in general, which is pointed out [here](http://phyweb.phys.soton.ac.uk/quantum/lectures/lm6.pdf) on page 2.

> The matrix $\chi$ is known as the susceptibility tensor, and is a tensor of rank 2. This is the most general representation of the susceptibility of a linear and uniform dielectric medium. It may be shown that, for a lossless and non-optically active material, $\chi_{ij}=\chi_{ji}$.

While the optically-inactive part does seem intuitive, I'm not sure what is meant by lossless medium in this case. Does it mean $\gamma = 0$ in the toy model? As far as I understand, the $\gamma$ is introduced to account for retarding motions due to presence of other atoms in surroundings. Another question: how do you describe a material to be optically inactive, i.e., what equations can one write using it?

Also, I did manage to find a [proof](http://www.umbc.edu/photonics/Menyuk/PhotSumTop10/DielTensSymm.pdf) for the symmetry of dielectric tensor. There are actually two proofs, one using Onsager's theorem and one using Fluctuation-Dissipation theorem. However, I'm looking for a much simpler proof, hopefully in the terms of energy and momentum conservation only, and not having any Thermodynamic machinery.

Edit: The first link is from the PHYS 3003 Light and Matter course page by Tim Freegarde, School of Physics & Astronomy, University of Southampton, UK.
The second link is titled "Symmetry of the Dielectric Tensor" by Curtis R. Menyuk, Computational Photonics Lab., UMBC.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1):

I think a short argument would be that the energy is, up to a multiplicative factor, given by $$U\sim P_iE_i=\chi_{ij}\, E_i\, E_j$$
Therefore, $\chi$ is nothing but $$\chi_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial E_i \partial E_j} $$
and therefore is symmetric.

Comment: It does not work as it stands: If $\chi_{ij}$ had an anti-symmetric part, $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial E_i \partial E_j}$ would see the symmetric part only, as the symmetric one would be canceled out in $U = \chi_{ij} E_iE_j$ in view of the symmetry of $E_iE_j$. However I suspect that some energetic reasoning proves the wanted symmetry.

Comment: The wanted symmetry is equivalent to say that $P_i \sim \frac{\partial U(E)}{\partial E_i}$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I agree with the math, but disagree with the interpretation. This whole $P\propto E$ relation is a linear response theory. It is derived the other way around: The energy, to leading order in $\vec E$, is given by $U\approx U_0 +\chi_{ij}E_iE_j$. The lack of a linear term is because $U$ is minimal when $\vec E=0$. Therefore, WLOG $\chi$ can be chosen to be symmetric. $P_i$ is **defined** as $\partial U/\partial E_i$.

Comment: But isn't this line of reasoning misleading/incorrect because it concludes that $\chi_{ij}$ is symmetric for all materials?

Comment: If $P$ is defined as you wrote (the definition I know is the one written by varun which is not equivalent to yours), there is no problem at all and $\chi$ is symmetric for all materials by definition, as varun stressed above. Is it the case?

Comment: I think it is. http://www.millersville.edu/~jdooley/macro/derive/elpol/alphasym/alphasym.htm